# LINQ query fails when counting an int

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query that takes a `DataTable` and counts the number of times a value appears in the `countField` column.

```
var countField = "class"
var query = from row in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
            group row by row.Field<string>(countField)
            into sumry
            orderby sumry.Count() descending
            select new
            {
                Text = sumry.Key,
                CountofRows = sumry.Count()
            };
```

This works as expected, unless the column contains decimal values. I am not familiar enough with `linq` to know what to change to allow it to count the instances of a decimal value.

How can I make this statement more robust so it will work for any data type contained in the indicated column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just fetch the value using `DataRow's` indexer and convert it to `string`:

```
var query = from row in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
        group row by row[countField].ToString()
        into sumry
        orderby sumry.Count() descending
        select new
        {
            Text = sumry.Key,
            CountofRows = sumry.Count()
        };
```

This should work as expected for all types.

Comment: I figured it would be easy. I tried converting it to a string, but not with the indexer. This works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the type of the column and use reflection to invoke `Field<T>()`.  (see this answer for invoking generic methods:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/232621/409259)

```
var columnType = myDataTable.Columns[countField].DataType;
var method = typeof(DataRowExtensions).GetMethod("Field", new Type[] { typeof(DataRow), typeof(string) });
var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(columnType);

var query = from row in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
            group row by generic.Invoke(null, new object[] { row, countField })
            into sumry
            orderby sumry.Count() descending
            select new
            {
                Text = sumry.Key,
                CountOfRows = sumry.Count()
            };
```

Comment: Does this offer an advantage over the answer by Selman22? It seems more complex, which isn't always bad, but I don't see what the extra code offers?

Comment: It only matters if `ToString()` would lose information that would distinguish different values.  For example, `DateTime.ToString()` formats times to the second.  If you needed to group by times at the millisecond, it wouldn't work for you.  I think for all other primitive types, and `DateTime` to the second, `ToString` would be fine.  For complex types, you would have to keep this in mind to make sure the grouping works as desired.